# JQuery clickable image + container separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a media-object set up like so:

```
<div class="row chatrow" userid='123'>
     <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src='image1.png' style="display: block;">
          </a>
         <div class="media-body">
             <h4 class="media-heading">User 1</h4>
             Hello, how are you doing?
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the `.chatrow` is clicked, the user is directed to a new page with javascript. However, I would like to allow the user to click on the image, and not be directed but instead display something. Currently I have tried:

```
$('a').on('click',function() {
    console.log('yes');
})
$('.chatrow').on('click',function() {
    window.location.href = "chat.php?id=" + $(this).attr('userid');
})
```

But this is redirecting every time it is clicked. Is it possible to prevent the direct on image click?

Comment: Try `$('.chatrow a').on('click',function(){})`

Answer (score 6):

You need to stop event from bubbling with `stopPropagation` method:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('link');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.chatrow').on('click', function() {
    alert('chatrow');
    //window.location.href = "chat.php?id=" + $(this).attr('userid');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row chatrow" userid='123'>
     <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/1' style="display: block;">
          </a>
         <div class="media-body">
             <h4 class="media-heading">User 1</h4>
             Hello, how are you doing?
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Normally click event (and others) bubble, it means that event travels up the DOM tree untill it reaches HTML root. You can prevent this behavior with `stopPropagation`.

Comment: *psst*, You never declared `e`.

Comment: What is the benefit to this answer as opposed to the answer below?

Comment: In this answer you explicitly say that you want prevent event bubbling. `return false` does this too but implicitly. Just pick the one you like more.

Answer (score 2):

You need a return false statement on the a tag  http://jsfiddle.net/cuxuLard/1/

```
    $('a.pull-left').on('click',function(e) {
        console.log('yes');
        return false;
    })
    $('.chatrow').on('click',function() {
        //window.location.href = "chat.php?id=" + $(this).attr('userid');
        console.log('chatrow');
    });
```

> return false; prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up")
>   the DOM. The you-may-not-know-this bit is that whenever an event
>   happens on an element, that event is triggered on every single parent
>   element as well. So let's say you have a box inside a box. Both boxes
>   have click events on them. Click on the inner box, a click will
>   trigger on the outer box too, unless you prevent propagation.

Source: [The difference between ‘return false;’ and ‘e.preventDefault();’](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Comment: It's true, in case of jQuery `return false` will also `stopPropagation` as well as `preventDefault`.